# Delete all TNT within a range

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was experimenting with redstone and command blocks and now I have tons of TNT scattered all over my (near) world. I know I shouldn't have scattered the TNT in the first place, but it's too late now, and I'm worried about a creeper blowing up my universe. Is there a way to turn them all into air? I thought of putting

```
/fill ~10 ~10 ~10 ~-10 ~-10 ~-10 air 0 replace tnt
```

in a repeating command block, or even entering

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~10 ~10 ~10 ~-10 ~-10 ~-10 air 0 replace tnt
```

but then I'd still have to run around my world for a few hours, getting close enough to TNT to delete it. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Why cant you just fill a larger region instead of a 10x10x10 cube?

Comment: Style tip: First enter the lower coordinates (negative in your case), then the positive. In this case, it would work the same, but in other cases you can get unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fill command is already the best you can do. You could make a system of self-cloning armor stands or command blocks, but that would generate more problems than it solves. But you can make a few improvements:

- Replace the 10s in your command with 15s to increase your reach:
  `execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~-15 ~-15 ~-15 ~15 ~15 ~15 air 0 replace tnt`
- If you know a range where the TNTs are, you can limit one coordinate and increase the others. For example if you know that they are all in the first three layers above the surface of a superflat world, you can use `execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~-51 ~-1 ~-51 ~51 ~1 ~51`.
- You can go into gamemode 3 and scroll the mousewheel up to increase your speed. Pressing the sprint key also helps.

And lastly, if the TNTs are close enough to each other, a flint and steel could solve your problem very quickly. ;)

Comment: Actually, if TNT so ignores other TNT when the mobGriefing gamerule is off, then don't and steel would actually be a valid option. You could make every entity noAI and noGravity before and give them a lot of resistance and knockback resistance. I'll try that this evening.

Comment: Yes, even with that gamerule, TNT ignites other TNTs. So you could for example treat all entities in your world with a command like `entitydata @e {NoAI:1,NoGravity:1,ActiveEffects:[{Id:11,Amplifier:4,Duration:72000}],Attributes:[{Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Base:1.0}]}` and afterwards reverse it. Or you could teleport them 1000 blocks upwards (with `NoGravity`), but I don't know how well some would react. Item frames and paintings would be destroyed in both ways. If you want me to write a complete answer about this, with details on how to revert, please say it and I'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at mcedit. But if your talking about doing it ingame and vanilla, there really isn't an easier way that isnt overcomplicated